# RegEx to check if specified word is not in string

Tags: regex

I am trying to learn RegEx and build a regular expression that would look whether specified word is NOT in the provided string. So far I did try [Regular Expression Info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) and [RexxEgg](http://www.rexegg.com/) all this tested on [Regular Expression Online](https://regex101.com/) but I did not find the answer to my question.

I have tried conditionals and lookarounds. Let's say I want to build an expression to test against not existing word **myword** and pass expression when the word is NOT in the string. I used expression

```
(?(?!myword).*)
```

but RegEx passes regardless the word **myword** meaning both strings `This is the text` and `This is myword the text` pass the test.

Using **negative lookahead** and conditions is used to test that condition is true when **myword** does not exist. Lookahead is also zero length and therefore `.*` would return the whole string.

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 3):

```
^(?(?!\bmyword\b).)*$
```

You can try this.See demo.Also use `\b` for matching exactly `myword` and not `mywords`

https://regex101.com/r/hI0qP0/7

Comment: Yes. It's working. thanks. The difference between mine and yours is you have only one dot and start behind brackets. Why is that?

Comment: @Celdor your regex said....check if there is `myword` then match all....this regex says....`at every point check if myword` is there or not....so the quantifier is outside and each `.` is being tested for myword....whereas in ur case it was being tested only once

Comment: Yes it works, thanks. I just need to read more about RegEx and lookaround. I find it quite confusing.

Comment: @Celdor `?!` is `negative lookahead`.So engine will look ahead to see if the match is not der.Only then it will pass.Your regex checks at the start if `myword` is not der.If that's ok it consumes the rest of ur string.See here https://regex101.com/r/hI0qP0/17

Answer (score 2):

You should use anchors and negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*?myword).*$
```

`(?!.*?myword)` is a negative lookahead that will fail the match if `myword` is found anywhere in the input string.